# Repeatedly asked to be verified of being a human

Tags: support, captcha

I am being repeatedly asked to be verified as a human evvery now and then, any help to avoid this?

p.s: its only happening in math and not other SO websites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Reduce the frequency of your posts and edits. That makes you look less like a robot.
2. [Earn a lot of rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53575/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing-for-5k-users).

Comment: lol, these days quick activity is also not recognised and is condemned :D